# Counting percentage of record from all records of given owner

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `owners` and `cars` table.

I want to compute single car's price contribution to all cars that owner own.

In same query i have to compute price contribution to sum of every car's price so i do it like

`student_37.cars.price::decimal/((SELECT SUM(price::decimal)`

But in the same query grouping by in select does not work because i do not have any connection to proper record :/ Any tips?

---

entire query but i know it does not make a sense

```
SELECT 
    name,
    student_37.cars.id AS car_id,
    CONCAT((ROUND(student_37.cars.price::decimal/((SELECT SUM(price::decimal) 
    FROM student_37.cars))*100)),'%'
    ) AS percentage,

    (student_37.cars.price::decimal/(SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM student_37.cars GROUP BY owner_id))
FROM student_37.owners
JOIN 
    student_37.cars     
ON 
    student_37.owners.id=student_37.cars.owner_id
```

Comment: Can you please provide your entire query ?

Comment: i have added it, im talking all about ```student_37.cars.price::decimal/(SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM student_37.cars GROUP BY owner_id)``` part because i do not know how to cope with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but this following query may help you or may be the solution :

```
SELECT
  o.name,
  c.id as car_id,
  ROUND((c.price/t.total)*100, 2) AS percentage
FROM 
  owner o
  JOIN car c ON o.id = c.owner_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT c.owner_id, SUM(c.price) AS total 
    FROM car c
    GROUP BY c.owner_id
  ) t ON t.owner_id = o.id
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ea256c9ec1232923fff8815a97784537)

Answer (score 1):

You should use window functions:

```
SELECT o.name, c.id as car_id,
     ROUND((c.price/ SUM(c.price) OVER (PARTITION BY c.owner_id)) * 100, 2) AS percentage
FROM owner o JOIN
     car c
     ON o.id = c.owner_id;
```

They are more efficient than a `JOIN`/`GROUP BY` combination.